# Google play not allowing HP Chromebook 14 G5

Tags: android, google-play, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os, androidappsonchromeos

I received an email from a client saying one of our apps only installs on "some" chromebooks but not on the HP Chromebook 14 G5.

I checked https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/chromium-os/chrome-os-systems-supporting-android-apps?visit_id=637873388265192668-2903345055&rd=1

Which states that this model supports Android apps. Our app uses the back camera for a qr code scanner and gps so I added these tags to the manifest

```
 <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.any"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
    android:required="false" />

<queries>
    <package android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
</queries>
```

These tags allow the app to install on "some" chromebooks but not all. Im honestly at a bit of a loss how to diagnose this problem further? Possibly the client hasnt the most updated chrome os version?

Any other ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the  HP Chromebook 14 G5 does not have a GPS or the particular Chromebook does not have a GPS driver installed. The fact that you have that `android:required="false"` made it show up in the list of supported apps.

Comment: So its the other way around, its not showing up as a supported app thats why I changed the gps to false.